# Post-processing in TBTrans

Tags: siesta, electronic-transport

I would like to write a simple code calculating Conductance and Seebeck coefficients in function of the chemical potential. To do this, I would like to use the equation:

$$L_n(\mu, T)=\frac{2}{h}\int T_e(E)(E-\mu)^n\frac{\partial f(E,\mu,T)}{\partial E}dE$$

reported in [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10825-012-0392-0) paper.

I plan to use the Transmission function calculated with TBTrans. However, I was wondering about the Temperature. I know that by default Transiesta uses 300K as electronic temperature. Is it right to assume 300K as T in this formula?

Comment: The link to the paper doesn't seem to work. It looks like a DOI, but I can't find it from searching that value.

Comment: Corrected! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have explicitly specified the temperature in a TranSiesta run via the electronic temperature you should rely on that temperature in the function you describe.

So the answer is yes. Be consistent about temperatures.